# grails/groovy braces syntax question

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm working with an example that I can't understand what the braces do -- the ones around the "Logout" in the second "out" statement below.  I guess the string is passed as a closure but I'm not getting the syntax beyond that. Can you please clarify?  Note the output of the code looks like the following:

John Doe [Logout]

---

```
class LoginTagLib {
  def loginControl = {
    if(request.getSession(false) && session.user){
      out << "Hello ${session.user.login} "
      out << """[${link(action:"logout",
             controller:"user"){"Logout"}}]"""
     } else {
       out << """[${link(action:"login",
       controller:"user"){"Login"}}]"""
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks Much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `link` tag takes attributes and a body, and as a regular GSP tag it's called like this:

```
<g:link action="logout" controller="user">Logout</g:link>
```

To invoke it as a method like you're doing, you need a way to pass the text ('Logout') to render in the link. If you look at the source of the tag (click "Show Source" at the bottom of http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) you'll see that the 2nd argument is `body`, and it's a Closure (although that's not clear from the code, but that's always the case for 2-parameter tags). `{"Logout"}` is a Closure that returns "Logout" since it's the last expression, so it's used as the body.

Comment: Question: shouldn't there be a comma before the {"Logout"} then, since it is the second parameter being passed?  i.e. per the Groovy 2 parameter closure example: def printSum = { a, b -> print a+b }
    printSum( 5, 7 )

Comment: No, the comma is optional when a Closure is the last parameter

Comment: Actually, the comma is not optional... placing the closure within the parentheses of the call is what's optional.  If the closure were passed into the function inside the parentheses, a comma would be necessary, i.e. func(a){clos} = func(a, {clos})

Answer (score 2):

Actually the output should be

```
Hello John Doe [Logout]
```

Essentially, if there is a session and a user write Hello user and create a link pointing to a logout action with the label Logout.

**{ "Logout" }** is a closure equivalent to **{ return "Logout"; }** as the last statement is used for a return value if none is explicitly stated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying / reminding in regard to the implicit return.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get the output like below

```
Hello John Doe [Logout]
```

Here is the output I am getting

> Hello jdoe [[Logout](/RaceTrack/user/logout)